# How to hide Terraform "artifactory" backend credentials?

Tags: terraform

Terraform 1.0.x

It's my first time using an `artifactory` backend to store my state files. In my case it's a Nexus repository, and followed [this article](https://medium.com/@arnobroekhof/using-sonatype-nexus-3-as-backend-provider-for-terraform-41e16d275fd7) to set up the repository.

I have the following

```
terraform {
  backend "artifactory" {
    # URL of Nexus-OSS repository
    url      = "http://x.x.x:8081/repository/"
    # Repository name (must be terraform)
    repo     = "terraform"
    # Unique path for this particular plan
    subpath  = "exa-v30-01"
    # Nexus-OSS creds (nust have r/w privs)
    username = "user"
    password = "password"
  }
}
```

Since the backend configuration does not accept variables for the `username` and `password` key/value pairs, how can I hide the credentials so they're not in plain site when I store my files in our Git repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the "Partial Configuration" section of the [Backend Configuration](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/settings/backends/configuration.html#partial-configuration) documentation. You have three options:

1. Specify the credentials in a backend config file (that isn't kept in version control) and specify the `-backend-config=PATH` option when you run `terraform init`.
2. Specify the credentials in the command line using the `-backend-config="KEY=VALUE"` option when you run `terraform init` (in this case, you would run `terraform init -backend-config="username=user" -backend-config="password=password"`).
3. Specify them interactively. If you just don't include them in the backend config block, and don't provide a file or CLI option for them, then Terraform should ask you to type them in on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

For settings related to authentication or identifying the current user running Terraform, it's typically best to leave those unconfigured in the Terraform configuration and use the relevant system's normal out-of-band mechanisms for passing credentials.

For example, for `s3` backend supports all of the same credentials sources that the AWS CLI does, so typically we just configure the AWS CLI with suitable credentials and let Terraform's backend pick up the same settings.

For systems that don't *have* a standard way to configure credentials out of band, the backends usually support environment variables as a Terraform-specific replacement. In the case of [the `artifactory` backend](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/settings/backends/artifactory.html) it seems that it supports `ARTIFACTORY_USERNAME` and `ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD` environment variables as the out-of-band credentials source, and so I would suggest setting those environment variables and then omitting `username` and `password` altogether in your backend configuration.

Note that this out-of-band credentials strategy is subtly different than using [partial backend configuration](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/settings/backends/configuration.html#partial-configuration). Anything you set as part of the backend configuration -- whether in a `backend` block in configuration or on the command line -- will be saved by Terraform into a local cache of your backend settings and into every plan file Terraform saves.

Partial backend configuration is therefore better suited to situations where the *location* of the state is configured systematically by some automation wrapper, and thus it's easier to set it on the command line than to generate a configuration file. In that case, it's beneficial to write out the location to the cached backend configuration so that you can be sure all future Terraform commands in that directory will use the same settings. It's *not* good for credentials and other sensitive information, because those can sometimes vary over time during your session and should ideally only be known temporarily in memory rather than saved as part of artifacts like the plan file.

Out-of-band mechanisms like environment variables and credentials files are handled directly by the backend itself and are not recorded directly by Terraform, and so they are a good fit for anything which is describing who is currently running Terraform, as opposed to where state snapshots will be saved.